# Using "C-x /" to access registers?

Tags: key-bindings

I used to be able to access Emacs registers with key sequence that were one item shorter. For example, I could jump to a point with `C-xj <register>`. This shortcut key seems to be gone in newer Emacsen. I'm wondering why these shortcuts went away and if there's any reason not to add them back.

Comment: I have always known the `C-x r` prefix used for register and rectangle commands. Are you sure `C-x / j <reg>` was the default binding? If so, which emacs version was that? `C-x r j <reg>` has always worked.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, I don't know the history but you can see `C-x/` and `C-xj` listed on some lists of key-bindings such as [this one](http://wttools.sourceforge.net/emacs-stuff/emacs-keybindings.html) where they are marked as "compatibility bindings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on kaushalmodi's answer I was able to dig the following explanation up of why these keys were deprecated (emphasis mine):

> ```
> C-x a
> C-x n
> C-x r
> ```
>
> Three new prefix keys have been created **to make many of the C-x commands more systematic**: C-x a, C-x n and C-x r. C-x a is used for abbreviation commands, C-x n for commands pertaining to narrowing, and C-x r for register and rectangle commands...

([source](http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/computers/download/manuals/emacs/emacs_34.htm#SEC272))

Comment: Such blogs tend to get outdated pretty quickly. You can use the emacs internal help bindings `C-h f` (to know what and if a command is bound to), `C-h k` (to know which command a binding executes) or simply refer to this [official emacs bindings reference card](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf).

Comment: `C-h f` and `C-h k` unfortunately don't give me any insight into _why_ the keys were deprecated (or even that the bindings ever existed), so are not a good substitute for the quoted text.

Comment: I agree, my comment was not meant as a substitute for the quoted text. I just gave few pointers to help figure out a command<->binding combination. The first thing I did on reading your original question was `C-h k C-x /` and with confidence I knew that that's not a default binding and then I proceeded to search for that in the emacs source code. If you knew what that binding bound to originally, you can see if it is still bound to anything using `C-h f`. Or you can search in the `refcard.pdf` to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a quick [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (*like grep, but better*) of the regular expression `'C-x\s*/'` in the emacs lisp source code gives the below as one of the results:

```
ChangeLog.12
1889:   C-x /, C-x j, C-x x, and C-x g (deprecated since Emacs 19).
18917:  item instead of "C-x/C-c/C-v (CUA)" if cua-enable-cua-keys is nil.
```

From [`ChangeLog.12`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/ChangeLog.12#n1888):

```
2007-02-11  Kim F. Storm  <storm@cua.dk>

    * bindings.el (ctl-x-map): Remove register compatibility bindings
    C-x /, C-x j, C-x x, and C-x g (deprecated since Emacs 19).
```

So looks like `C-x /` is one of the bindings long deprecated. You can, though, always define your own bindings. Have a look at this Elisp Manual page on [How to set key bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html).

Comment: @kuzzooroo I have updated my answer with more info. You can instead do `grep -r 'C-x\s*/' *`.